# How to clear multiple youtube url of iframe tag in modal popup?

Tags: asp.net, youtube, modal-dialog

I have a modal pop up in which I am displaying youtube videos. The problem I am facing is video is playing even though I closed the modal popup. I have cleared url on modal hide. But it clears only one url. Rest urls are not clearing. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      /* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url
      and store it in a variable */
      var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');

      /* Assign empty url value to the iframe src attribute when
      modal hide, which stop the video playing */
      $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');
      });

      /* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src
      attribute when modal is displayed again */
      $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
           $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
      });

  });
```

Comment: Would be possible clear the div that contains such iframe and (*instead of add the url back to the iframe's src*), build the `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

@Sachin,
You need to set **Common class** to your modal supposed you have created multiple modal and add the same class.

I think you are working as below demo HTML.

```
    Like Eg.
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   

  </div>
</div>
```

**You need to set a common class**

and also set *iframe tag, common class.

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade jsyoutube" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   
    <iframe src="URL" class="jsframe"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade jsyoutube"  role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   
<iframe src="URL" class="jsframe"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade jsyoutube" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">   
<iframe src="URL" class="jsframe"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

***javascript script***

```
    $(document).ready(function() {     
      $(".jsyoutube").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            $(".jsframe").attr('src', '');
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi @jishan siddique, thanks for the code. But sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using modal slider, in which I will be displaying youtube videos. User plays one video in one slider, slides to next video, plays that. Then closes it. At that time not all the videos are stopped. Only one video is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="modal-body">
<!--<p>One fine body…</p>-->

      <iframe id="siparis_goruntule" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

and link

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" onclick="JavaScript:siparis_goruntule.src='http://siparis.company.com/id=<?=$siparis_id?>';" >Sipariş Görüntüle</a>
```